# Missing Purpose String in Info.plist for Photo access

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting this response when submitting my app to the store.

*ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs.

The following image shows what I have in the info.plist file. I do not understand where the issue is?

[image]

Comment: Right click on the plist file. Show source code, you'll see which on you have. Also, you can add a new key in the plist mode, and copy/paste that key, you'll see it's "human redable version" which is different: "Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description" for "NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription" and "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" for "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription"

Comment: Please, What about these two keys value ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` key to your plist file. At least that's what your screen shot says. `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` is the write-only access to the Photos app. On the other hand, if you would like to request the read or write access to the Photos app, use this key: `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`

Here's a screenshot of both keys in Info.plist when viewed as a property list file on Xcode:

[image]
The first one is the `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` and the second one is the `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` key.

So, if you have any code (or a library) that is trying to read from the photo library, then you are required to add the `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` key.

Comment: I'm working on an app that work in simulator on Xcode 10 and 11, and might even have been submitted for TestFlight before, but circa Xcode 11 / iOS 14, it seems that the App Store submissions require this `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`, even if your app has more limited access and does not ever need this "purpose string".

Comment: Please, What about these two keys value !?